# Changing color of content tabs populated using a wordpress plugin?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, tabs

I'm using a Wordpress plugin called Responsive Tabs (by WP Darko) to populate different content in tabs for an educational site I am working on.  I'm trying to change the color of each of the 5 tabs to be different from the default color option I choose in the plugin settings.  I've been told by the plugin support team that this is possible using CSS but I can't figure it out and I cannot pay them to do it as we are a public funded school district and there is no way I'm going to get budget approval to have somebody change the colors of something on a website.

This is the test site:  http://www.wcsddata.net/test/

I've only included the plugin on the site.  I want to change the color of the tab and also the top border of the content area under the tab when selected (you can see they are both the same color now).

I've tried tons of variations of the tab classes ".1189-tab-link-0", ".1189-tab-link-1" etc. and am getting nowhere!

Any help determining which classes will get the job done would be hugely appreciated!  Then using the !important tag should get the job done.  Right?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if I have to change it in the javascript?  I would hate to do that though as the support team told me it can be done in CSS.  JS below.

Comment: var rtbs_def_colors = {
        backgroundColor : 'transparent',
    };
        
    $j('.rtbs').each(function(){
        var color = $j(this).find('.rtbs_color').html();
        var breakpoint = $j(this).find('.rtbs_breakpoint').html();
        var rtbssize = $j(this).width();
        if (rtbssize > breakpoint) {
            $j(this).removeClass('rtbs_full');
            $j(this).find(".mobile_toggle").hide();
            $j(t

Answer (score 0):

Man maybe you want to change color when tab is active :D
Try this

```
classname:active { background-color: red; }
```

or text color change

```
classname:active { color: red; }
```

the same approach to change border..

Comment: Are you able to add your class in html file find that links in the file and for example  `<a href="..." class="1189-tab-link-0 my-class">`  and then target both in css file

Answer (score 0):

The HTML on your page uses inline style, e.g. :

```
<li class="mobile_toggle">&zwnj;</li><li class="current"><a style="background:#f19803" class="active 1189-tab-link-0" href="#" data-tab="#1189-tab-0">Self-Awareness</a></li>
```

In order to change the color, change the hexidecimal value #f19803. Because this has the entire list of links selected, it will change the color for all of them. Inline styling is not a best practice, but to change each individual link you could change the background color of each individual li tag by adding a style="background:#(hex color)" to each one. Example:

```
<a style="background:#ff55ff" href="#" data-tab="#1189-tab-2" class="1189-tab-link-2">Social Awareness</a></li>
```

Comment: I understand this, thank you.  I also went and gave it a go but it doesn't work because I am using a plugin and the plugin uses PHP and CSS to implement the HTML you are seeing when you view source.  In CSS, do you know how I can change this:

<a class="1189-tab-link-1" href="#" data-tab="#1189-tab-1" style="background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">Self-Management</a>

Comment: In the CSS section (between the style tags) you would need to select each tag by reference to their class. Here this would be done with .1189-tab-link-1 {background: #ff00ff; etc.}. I think that the reason you have not been able to select these tags with class alone is because other selectors in the CSS have greater precedence because they are more specific. Making your selectors more specific requires selecting the li and a along with the class.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried this (below) to no avail.  Thoughts?

Comment: .1189-tab-link-1 ul li {
    background-color: #ff55ff !important; 
}

.1189-tab-link-1 ul li a {
    background-color: #ff55ff !important; 
}

.1189-tab-link-1 li {
    background-color: #ff55ff !important; 
}

.1189-tab-link-1 a {
    background-color: #ff55ff !important; 
}

Comment: I gave this another look and on JS fiddle I was able to change the individual tab highlight color for each with inline color changes to the div elements surrounding each tbody. The id for the first tab's div is 1189-tab-0, and then 1189-tab-1, etc. Perhaps try selecting #1189-tab-0 with CSS, or make an inline change, and see if that works for you with your plugin.